# how to get a list of commits from refChanges in Atlassian Stash Pre Receive Repository Hook

Tags: bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Im trying to write a stash plugin that will iterate through the commits in a change set pushed to stash in a Pre Receive Repository Hook.

The API passes a Collection of refChange in the onReceive method.

```
public boolean onReceive(RepositoryHookContext context, Collection<RefChange> refChanges, HookResponse hookResponse)
```

if I make 3 commits then push I get one RefChange which looks like this

```
refId = refs/heads/master
fromHash = ded3e4583653f14892cc3e8a898ba74ee75e1a58 // First Commit in change set
toHash = ae017dcdadf7ca69617fb05f6905cccfe2aa4229 // Most recent commit
type = "UPDATE"
```

Id like to get a collection of all the commits so that I can get all the commit messages.

I'm looking at com.atlassian.stash.commit.CommitService getCommit and getCommits.  I think I need to getCommitsBetween but can't quite figure out how to crate the GetCommitsBetween parameter needed from the RefChange I have.

Am I even heading down the right path here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the `CommitsBetweenRequest` page on the Atlassian Stash API documentation is one of the few pages with an explanation, it took some trial and error to figure this out. `GetCommitsBetween` works but here's the trick...

Set the `commitsBetweenBuilder.exclude` to the starting commit in the change set and `commitsBetweenBuilder.include` to the ending commit hash.

```cs
CommitsBetweenRequest.Builder commitsBetweenBuilder = new CommitsBetweenRequest.Builder(context.getRepository() );
commitsBetweenBuilder.exclude(refChange.getFromHash()); //Starting with
commitsBetweenBuilder.include(refChange.getToHash()); // ending with

PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequestImpl(0,6);

Page<Commit> commits = commitService.getCommitsBetween(commitsBetweenBuilder.build(), pageRequest);

//TODO: handle Pages
for (Commit commit : commits.getValues()) {
   hookResponse.out().println("Message = " + commit.getMessage() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: How are you using the `commitService` ? i'm trying to figure out how to initialize it

Comment: I believe it gets injected via the constructor...  
    `public class myClass implements AsyncPostReceiveRepositoryHook, RepositorySettingsValidator {  
private final CommitService commitService;  
    
    public myClass(CommitService commitService, NavBuilder navBuilder) {
        this.commitService = commitService;  
        this.navBuilder = navBuilder;  
    }`

Comment: When I use this constructor for some reason it disables my plugin completely, when I refresh my repository hooks it disappear from the list... how can I implement this?

Answer (score -2):

I wasn't able to get the dependency injection working for the CommitService.  Spring for some reason wasn't able to find it, when trying to run in locally ???

I did getting it working using the component locator.

```
CommitService commitService = ComponentLocator.getComponent(CommitService.class);
```