# Getting user that initiated push to pre-receve hook

Tags: atlassian-plugin-sdk

I´m developing a pre-receive hook with the atlassian-plugin-sdk and I need to get the user name of the user who pushed the changes. So what I want to get inside the hook is what I locally can get with 'git config user.name', is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use `AuthenticationContext` to get the current authenticated user. See the example:

```
@Component
public class BlockInvalidRefPreReceiveRepositoryHook extends TaboolaBaseHook implements PreRepositoryHook<RepositoryHookRequest> {

    private final AuthenticationContext authenticationContext;

    @Autowired
    public BlockInvalidRefPreReceiveRepositoryHook(@ComponentImport AuthenticationContext authenticationContext) {
        this.authenticationContext = authenticationContext;
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public RepositoryHookResult preUpdate(@Nonnull PreRepositoryHookContext preRepositoryHookContext,
                                          @Nonnull RepositoryHookRequest repositoryHookRequest) {
        if (!isValidTrigger(repositoryHookRequest.getTrigger())){
            return RepositoryHookResult.accepted();
        }

        ApplicationUser currUser = this.authenticationContext.getCurrentUser();

        for (RefChange refChange : repositoryHookRequest.getRefChanges()) {
            if (refChange.getType() == RefChangeType.ADD && refChange.getRef().getType() == StandardRefType.TAG) {
                // Allow only specific user to push tags
                if (currUser.getType() == UserType.NORMAL && !currUser.getName().equals("validUserToPushTags")) {
                    return RepositoryHookResult.rejected("Only user validUserToPushTags is able to push tags",
                            "Only user validUserToPushTags is able to push tags");
                }
            }
        }
        return RepositoryHookResult.accepted();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are making a bitbucket plugin. You can get commit information by registering a CommitCallback to the PreRepositoryHook. Below code is untested, but it should fetch the author of a commit.

```
public class CommitMessageHook implements PreRepositoryHook<RepositoryHookRequest> {
    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public RepositoryHookResult preUpdate(@Nonnull PreRepositoryHookContext context, @Nonnull RepositoryHookRequest request) {

        // hook only when a commit is added to the repository
        context.registerCommitCallback(
                new CommitCallback(),
                RepositoryHookCommitFilter.ADDED_TO_REPOSITORY);

        return RepositoryHookResult.accepted();
    }

    private static class CommitCallback implements PreRepositoryHookCommitCallback {

        private RepositoryHookResult result = RepositoryHookResult.accepted();

        @Nonnull
        @Override
        public RepositoryHookResult getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCommitAdded(@Nonnull CommitAddedDetails commitDetails) {
            Commit commit = commitDetails.getCommit();
            Person author = commit.getAuthor();
            String authorName = author.getName();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is better ways to get commits related to a given request. . Take a look at `CommitService` and `CommitsBetweenRequest`. See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052592/how-to-get-a-list-of-commits-from-refchanges-in-atlassian-stash-pre-receive-repo#29054081. Beside that, `authenticationContext.getCurrentUser()` is the way to go.